# what should i set the scope of beans in different layers of my web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

what should i set the scope of beans in different layers of my web app every controllers in my app has an instance variable of beans in service layer autowired & every bean in service layer has a bean autowired from DAO layer & every bean in DAO layer has sessionfactory autowired which is thread safe since controllers in spring are singleton by default & thats same for every other beans so i 'm confused what should be the scope of beans in each layer so application didnt ran into concurrency issues ???

Comment: Could you re-frame your question so that its more readable?

Comment: singletons are the default, and there's no reason to change that for controllers, services and DAOs, since they should have no state at all (except for references to their Spring bean dependencies).